# Look up User through model

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model defined something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
```

After the user logs in, I look up the user:

```
user = authenticate(username=usr, password=pwd)
```

How do I get the Person object which is related to this user?

```
person = Person.objects.filter(user=usr) # I guess not like this...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pre django v1.5?
If so: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

also, you could create a simple property:

```
User.person = property(lambda u: Person.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

... so when you want to access a user's person attributes:

```
user.person.attribute_a
```

django 1.5 now has custom user models (making Person kinda irrelevant)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/#customizing-the-user-model

Comment: I have several kinds of user which extend the built in User, so would really like to be able to look up these based on the 'User'. No way of doing this?

Comment: could you post your models so I can understand the question a little better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the general querying method for OneToOne relationship in Django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships

Technically you could do what you wrote:

```
person = Person.objects.filter(user=usr)
```

This is because Django also creates backward relationship.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#how-are-the-backward-relationships-possible

Example,

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    # You should actually use django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    funny_comment = models.TextField()

user = authenticate(username=usr, password=pwd)
user.userdetail # return the user detail object
```

I think you need a custom user model (in version 1.5) only if you are doing custom authentication or if you just want to add a couple of fields. If you want to store detail profile information you should make OneToOne relationship with user model and you can query linked models like any regular model relationship.